# Edit and Load HTML from local file in Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have a .html file stored in my project bundle. When I load it in WebView.(UIWebview/WKWebview) the data is loaded but the table structure in it isn't visible. The table borders, columns , rows. The values are just floating . In Chrome browser it opens properly.

```
let myURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "prescription", withExtension: "html")
    let myURLRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(myURLRequest)
```

**Chrome browser** : 
[image: This is how it looks in browser]

**iOS App UIWebView :**

[image: This is how it looks in UIWebview]

The Html page is made responsive to fit in any sizes but I am not able to load in UIWebview properly as Web.
I need to store the file locally because I need to make changes to its values and show on webview.

Comment: try this ....convert file into html string and load with converted string..using [webView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:nil]

Comment: In Safari browser, does it works? Because WKWebView should use Safari tools (and internal parsing/interpreting tags).

Comment: Do you have external references like stylesheets?

Comment: @AyushYadav have loaded the html using the same. In fact tried all techniques. (Direct pass html file path, convert to string and pass.)

Comment: @Larme yes it works and displays correctly in safari browser.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Yes the html has stylesheets. Something like this <link href="https://cxcx.something.com/libs/normalize/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="./someasset/stylesheets/default.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution :
 If you are applying some local css whose path is there in HTML file.
viz.

1. Add that css file "myDefault.css" to your xcode project directory.
2. Convert the HTML to string and replace the path of css in HTML file with your local path. :
3. Load the content of HTML to UIWebView with base url. (Providing local file path as baseUrl is important)

   ```
   webView = UIWebView()

   let pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "presc", ofType: "html")
   let pathToHTMLCSS = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myDefault", ofType: "css")
   do {
       var strHTMLContent = try String(contentsOfFile: pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate!)

       strHTMLContent = strHTMLContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "./assets/stylesheets/myDefault.css", with: pathToHTMLCSS!)

   let pdfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToInvoiceHTMLTemplate!)
   webView.loadHTMLString(strHTMLContent, baseURL: pdfURL)

   }catch let err{
       print(err)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When loading local content into the `WKWebView`, you shoudl use `loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:)` instead of `loadRequest`. The first function allows you to provide a base URL, which you will also let point into the bundle - so you clearly need to add all the relevant files to your application bundle.

```
guard let indexPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html"),
   let content =  try String(contentsOfFile: indexPath, encoding: .utf8),
   let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: indexPath) else {
        // Error handling
   }
webView.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: baseUrl)
```